# turn 2 columns in table to custom string using lambda IN asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have table with those columns :

```
Id
Name
Active
Date
```

I need to get all rows in table that contains "Barak" in Name column.
also, I need to return it in this format "Id - Name" using asp.net.

can someone help me?

Comment: when i needed only one column it was easy. i put this function : return dbEntities.Cases.Select(D => D.Id.ToString()).Where((D) => D.StartsWith(Id)).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
from t in tableName
where t.Name.Contains(@"Barak")
select new
{
   ConCatString= t.Id.ToString() + "-" + t.Name
};
```

Or

```
return dbEntities.Cases.Where(s => s.Name.Contains("Barak")).Select( c => new {CombinedString=string.Format("{0} {1} {2}" ,c.ID , " - " ,c.Name)}).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you very much, looks great, but now my problem is to return it as List<string>.
how can i do it?...I'm talking about you second option

Comment: add .ToList(); at end to get List of String

Comment: I get error:
Error 10 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: is someone can help somehow?